# JavaScript Regular Expression Validation

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm attempting to validate a field name to match a certain format in JavaScript using Regular Expressions. 

I need the string inputted to resemble this:

word\word\word

So anything inputted can't be blank, and it must be three words seperated by a backslash.

This is the code i'm working with, but i'm not sure if the pattern is the right syntax?!!

```
    function validateResourceName() {
       //get posted resource name value
       var inputString = document.getElementById("resourceName").value;
       //should be in the word\word\word format
       var pattern=/[a-Z|/\\/|a-Z|/\\/|a-Z\s]/;

       //If the inputString is NOT a match
       if (!pattern.test(inputString)) {
        alert("not a match");
       }
      else
      {
            alert("match");
      }
    }
```

Any help will be very appreciated!!!

Comment: `/^[a-zA-Z]+\/[a-zA-Z]+\/[a-zA-Z]+$/` will evaluate it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just use this `\w+\\\w+\\\w+`

or

```
[a-zA-Z]+(\\[a-zA-Z]+){2}
```

Comment: `\w` does more than what he appears to want (it includes digits and such)

Comment: This would include digits and underscores

Comment: pls see wiki they clearly mention to match words we should use \w

Comment: @raghavendra: What the wiki wants and what the OP wants aren't necessarily the same thing. In particular, underscores aren't part of a "word" in English.

Comment: @raghavendra: Well, the OP hasn't weighed in with what they consider a "word," so... (But probably not underscores, to be fair.)

Answer (score 4):

Try `/^[a-z]+\\[a-z]+\\[a-z]+$/`

```
function validateResourceName() {
  //get posted resource name value
  var inputString = document.getElementById("resourceName").value;
  //should be in the word\word\word format
  var pattern=/^[a-z]+\\[a-z]+\\[a-z]+$/
  //If the inputString is NOT a match
  if (!pattern.test(inputString)) {
    alert("not a match");
  } else {
    alert("match");
  }
}
```

If you want to allow the word matching to be case insensitive;

```
`/^[a-z]+\\[a-z]+\\[a-z]+$/i`
```

If you want to be a bit more broad with what you define as a 'word', and allow it to consist of alphanumeric characters and underscore;

```
`/^\w+\\\w+\\\w+$/i`
```

Answer (score 3):

If by word you mean the English letters a-z in upper or lower case, then:

```
/^(?:[a-z]+\\){2}[a-z]+$/i
```

That says:

- `^` Beginning of string
- `(?:...)` Non-capturing group
- `[a-z]+` One or more letters a-z (or A-Z because of the `i` flag at the end). If you also want to allow some other characters, just add them to the `[a-z]` after the `z`. If you want to allow hyphens, add `\-` to it (you need the backslash, depending on where you put the hyphen, so I just always include it). Note that this is very English-centric, and even in English sometimes people write borrowed words with their non-English letters, such as résumé.
- `\\` Backslash
- `{2}` Repeated twice
- (Then another word)
- `$` End of string

The issues with your expression are:

- `[a-Z]` Is invalid because the range is out of order (`Z` comes before `a`). If it **were** valid (or if you wrote `[Z-a]`), it would matches **everything** between `Z` and `a`, which isn't just `a-z` and `A-Z`
- `\\/` Requires a backslash and then a slash
- `|` is an *alternation* (this or that)
- `\s` is whitespace

Comment: I get `Invalid regular expression` in Chrome using `[a-Z]`. *Range out of order in character class*

Comment: @RGraham: I'm glad to hear that. :-) Yeah, it would have to be `[Z-a]` to get the order right, since `Z` comes before `a`. (Some regex engines in other languages just quietly reverse the range for you, I think.)

Comment: And of course, `Z-a` wouldn't match `A-Y` or `b-z`. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
^\w+\\\w+\\\w+$
```

In javascript

```
if (/^\w+\\\w+\\\w+$/.test(subject)) {
    // Successful match
} else {
    // Match attempt failed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7p36L92j/) for the code demo.

Regex

```
/(\w)*\\(?!\\)(\w)*\\(?!\\)(\w)*(?!\\)/g
```

JavaScript

```
function validateResourceName(string) {
 var pattern = /(\w)*\\(?!\\)(\w)*\\(?!\\)(\w)*(?!\\)/g;
  if (!pattern.test(string)) {
    alert("not a match");
  } else {
    alert("match");
  }
}
```

Comment: This allows for an empty word: `var string = '\\\\';`

Answer (score 0):

Here I came up with a robust solution where you can find everything in one place. In function, you can find all types of validation in the same method with the proper message.

**For JavaScript Users...**

```
function validateInput(input,type,max,min,confirmPassword ='' ){
            input = input.toLocaleString();

            const validateMaxLength = (maxLen) => input.length <= maxLen;
            const validateMinLength = (minLen) => input.length >= minLen;
            const validateNotEmpty = () => input.trim() !== '';

            if( !validateMaxLength(max) ){
                return {status:'error',msg:'String is too long.'};
            }
            else if( !validateMinLength(min))
                return    {status:'error',msg:'String is too short.'};

            else if( !validateNotEmpty() ){
                return   {status:'error',msg:'String can not empty.'};
            }
           else if( type === 'email'){
                const emailRegex = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/;
                if( !emailRegex.test(input) ){
                    return  {status:'error',msg:'Email is not valid.'};;
                }
                return {status:'success',msg:""};
            }
            else if ( type === 'alphanumeric' )
            {
                const alphanumericRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+$/;
                if( !alphanumericRegex.test(input) ){
                    return  {status:'error',msg:'String is not valid.'};
                }
                return {status:'success',msg:""};
            }
            else if ( type === 'onlyString' )
            {
                const stringRegex = /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/;
                if( !stringRegex.test(input) ){
                    return  {status:'error',msg:'Email is not valid.'};
                }
                return {status:'success',msg:""};
            }
            else if ( type === 'onlyNumber' )
            {
                const numberRegex = /^[0-9]+$/;
                if( !numberRegex.test(input)  ){
                    return  {status:'error',msg:'Number is not valid.'};
                }
                return {status:'success',msg:""};
            }
            else if ( type === 'mobileNumber' )
            {
                const mobileRegex = /^[+\s0-9]+$/;

                if( !mobileRegex.test(input) ){
                    return  {status:'error',msg:'Mobile number is invalid.'};
                }
                return {status:'success',msg:""};
            }
            else if ( type === 'alphanumericWithSpecial' )
            {
                const alphanumericSpecialRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?\s]*$/;

                if( !alphanumericSpecialRegex.test(input) ){
                    return  {status:'error',msg:'String is not valid.'};
                }
                return {status:'success',msg:""};
            }
            else if ( type === 'webURL' )
            {
                const urlRegex = /^(ftp|http|https):\/\/[^ "]+$/;

                if( !urlRegex.test(input) ){
                    return  {status:'error',msg:'Web url is not valid.'};
                }
                return {status:'success',msg:""};
            }
            else if ( type === 'confirmPassword' )
            {
                if (input !== confirmPassword.toString()) {
                    return  {status:'error',msg:'Passwords do not match.'};
                }
                return {status:'success',msg:""};
            }
                return  {status:'error',msg:"Invalid Type"};
        }
```

**Use Case :**

```
 Console.log( validateInput("pankajJiAppMahanHo@domin.com","email",80,10 ) )
```

**For VUE JS :**

```
 methods:{  
      validateInput(input,type,max,min,confirmPassword ='' ){
            input = input.toLocaleString();

            const validateMaxLength = (maxLen) => input.length <= maxLen;
            const validateMinLength = (minLen) => input.length >= minLen;
            const validateNotEmpty = () => input.trim() !== '';

            if( !validateMaxLength(max) ){
                return {status:'error',msg:'String is too long.'};
            }
            else if( !validateMinLength(min))
                return    {status:'error',msg:'String is too short.'};

            else if( !validateNotEmpty() ){
                return   {status:'error',msg:'String can not empty.'};
            }
           else if( type === 'email'){
                const emailRegex = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/;
                if( !emailRegex.test(input) ){
                    return  {status:'error',msg:'Email is not valid.'};;
                }
                return {status:'success',msg:""};
            }
            else if ( type === 'alphanumeric' )
            {
                const alphanumericRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+$/;
                if( !alphanumericRegex.test(input) ){
                    return  {status:'error',msg:'String is not valid.'};
                }
                return {status:'success',msg:""};
            }
            else if ( type === 'onlyString' )
            {
                const stringRegex = /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/;
                if( !stringRegex.test(input) ){
                    return  {status:'error',msg:'Email is not valid.'};
                }
                return {status:'success',msg:""};
            }
            else if ( type === 'onlyNumber' )
            {
                const numberRegex = /^[0-9]+$/;
                if( !numberRegex.test(input)  ){
                    return  {status:'error',msg:'Number is not valid.'};
                }
                return {status:'success',msg:""};
            }
            else if ( type === 'mobileNumber' )
            {
                const mobileRegex = /^[+\s0-9]+$/;

                if( !mobileRegex.test(input) ){
                    return  {status:'error',msg:'Mobile number is invalid.'};
                }
                return {status:'success',msg:""};
            }
            else if ( type === 'alphanumericWithSpecial' )
            {
                const alphanumericSpecialRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?\s]*$/;

                if( !alphanumericSpecialRegex.test(input) ){
                    return  {status:'error',msg:'String is not valid.'};
                }
                return {status:'success',msg:""};
            }
            else if ( type === 'webURL' )
            {
                const urlRegex = /^(ftp|http|https):\/\/[^ "]+$/;

                if( !urlRegex.test(input) ){
                    return  {status:'error',msg:'Web url is not valid.'};
                }
                return {status:'success',msg:""};
            }
            else if ( type === 'confirmPassword' )
            {
                if (input !== confirmPassword.toString()) {
                    return  {status:'error',msg:'Passwords do not match.'};
                }
                return {status:'success',msg:""};
            }
                return  {status:'error',msg:"Invalid Type"};
        } ,
    debounceEmailValidation: _.debounce( function (){
          let d =  this.validateInput(this.email,'email',50,10 );
          if( d.status === 'error'){
                this.errors={email:[ d.msg]};
                return
            }
            this.errors={email:[]};
        }, 1000),
  },
 watch:{
        'email':{
            handler(){
                 this.debounceEmailValidation();
            }
        }
     },
```

**debounceMobileValidation** using **debounce** is not mandatory. I used it because there was a need for a program.