# regular expression to validate a pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, validation, material-ui

I am new to regular expression, In my project i am allowing user to put amount in shorthand as well as full digit, i have used material UI TextField for input.

Examples are:

```
400k - shorthand, 

400.2k - shorthand, 

4m - shorthand,

500. - should work

500000 - full amount
```

some pattern user should not be allowed to enter example are:

```
4.2.k, 

.3k, 

4...k

300.k
```

I have written regex which is below but it does allows to enter dot after number.

```
textValue.match(/^[0-9]*(\.[0-9]{0,2})*([0-9km]{1})$/) && textValue.match(/^[\d]+/)
```

above code first regex validates the pattern and second regex forces user to put Number because amount cannot start with string, i have wrote two separate regex as i don't understand how to put them in one regex and those regex doesn't accepts dot after number. Please can anyone give a perfect Regex to validate the above pattern in one single regular expression??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does [this](https://regex101.com/r/AjOLEr/4) help?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it does allows to enter dot after number example 500. should work.

Comment: You want to allow a dot after 500?

Comment: yes bro because i am restricting user to enter any other character in TextField, if i don't allow user to put dot the he cannot 500.2k because we are not allowing it.

Comment: @DaveSmith Ok, I have added an update.

Comment: Can `5.5` also be a match?

Comment: And also `5.` be a match?

Comment: you can visit my answer in which I covered all validation for Form or other places. Visit my Link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/78050480/4335210

Answer (score 2):

With alternation (never really the prettiest) it could be done like:

```
^\d+([km]|\.|\.\d+[km])?$
```

See the [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/z8ahBM/3)

- `^` - Start string ancor.
- `d+` - One or more digits.
- `(` - Opening capturing group (you could use non-capturing).

  - `[km]` - A single character "k" or "m".
  - `|` - Alternation (OR).
  - `\.?` - A literal dot.
  - `|` - Alternation (OR).
  - `\.\d+[km]` - A literal dot followed by at least one digit and a character "k" or "m".
  - `)?` - Close capturing group and make it optional
- `$` - Start string ancor.

---

[image]

Comment: That is nice and short ++. (You could make it non capturing `(?:` if you don't need the group)

Answer (score 1):

*About the pattern you tried*

Note that you don't need `{1}`. The character class `[0-9km]` matches 1 of a char `k` or `m` or a digit 0-9. This way the possible digits to match could be 0-3 instead of 0-2.

Using the quantifier `*` for the group makes it possbile to also match `400.25.22.22.22k`

---

You could use this pattern to validate the examples. The `[0-9]+` at the beginning of the pattern makes sure that there has to be at least a single digit present.

If you want to allow `500.` you could use:

```
^[0-9]+(?:(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?[km]?|\.)$
```

*Explanation*

- `^` Start of string
- `[0-9]+` Match 1+ digits
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?` Match an optional decimal part with 2 digits
  - `[km]?` Match optional `k` or `m`
  - `|` Or
  - `\.` Match a single dot
- `)$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/W7onSo/1)

```js
let pattern = /^[0-9]+(?:(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?[km]?|\.)$/;
[
  "400k",
  "400.2k",
  "4m",
  "500000",
  "500.",
  "300.k",
  "4.2.k",
  ".3k",
  "4...k",
].forEach(s => console.log(s + " --> " + pattern.test(s)));
```

---

Another option is to only match the dot when not directly followed by `k` or `m`

```
^[0-9]+(?:\.(?![km]))?\d*[km]?$
```

[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/hJFybr/1)

Comment: only one flaw is there, it allow to enter 300.k, shouldn't happen.

Comment: @DaveSmith You can either match the optional digits and km, or the digits followed by a dot. See update.

Comment: With your 2nd pattern you are matching `5.5` which makes sense but not sure if OP needs it. If he does than my answer wouldn't cater for it either which makes this pretty cool. As usual you got my vote down =)

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
^\d+\.?(?:\d+)?[KkMm]?(?<!\.[KkMm])$
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

> **`^, $`** - Matches start and end of the line respectively.
>
> **`\d+`** - Matches digits 1 or more times.
>
> **`\.?`** - Represents 0 or 1 occurrence of `.`.
>
> **`[KkMm]?`** - Matches optional characters from the mentioned character class.
>
> **`(?<!\.[KkMm])`** - Represents a negative look-behind not matching a a character after `.`.

You can find the demo of the above regex in [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/AjOLEr/10)

[image: Pictorial Representation]

```js
const regex = /^\d+\.?(?:\d+)?[KkMm]?(?<!\.[KkMm])$/gm;
const str = `400K
4.2.K
4.3K
3.2M
300000
4....K
4K
500.
300.K`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`${match}`);
    });
}
```

---

**2nd efficient solution using alternation:**

You can probably try this regex for more efficient implementation

```
^\d+(?:\.$|\.\d+)?[KkMm]?$
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

> **`^, $`** - Matches start and end of the line respectively.
>
> **`\d+`** - Matches digits 1 or more times.
>
> **`(?:\.$|\.\d+)?`** - Represents a non-capturing group; matching either numbers followed by only `.` or decimal numbers.
>
> **`[KkMm]?`** - Matches one of the mentioned characters zero or 1 time.

You can find the demo of the above regex in [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/z8ahBM/4)

[image: Pictorial representation-2]

```js
const regex = /^\d+(?:\.$|\.\d+)?[KkMm]?$/gm;
const str = `400K
4.2.K
4.3K
3.2M
300000
4....K
4K
500.
300.K`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
// The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
    console.log(`${match}`);
   });
}
```

Comment: only one flaw is there, it allow to enter 300.k, shouldn't happen, after dot there shouldn't be k or m

Comment: Just noticed I'm the only one that's probably misinterpreting the question. Both your patterns and that of @TheFourthBird do allow for `5.5`. And this sounds legit, yet in the context of [km] it could also be wrong, since you can't say 5.5 of nothing. Sounds vague? Either way, OP should clarify =)