# Validating inputs using JavaScript RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, dom

I'm having this JS function to verify the user input and ensure it's a year between 2000-2021, it's working great, the problem is when I write invalid input it changes the outline to red, however when I write a valid input it's remain red. And even if I write valid input from the beginning it goes red.

```
var  batchRegex=/^[2][0][0-2][0-1]$/;
function checkBatch(batch){
if (batch = ""){
  document.getElementById('batch').style.outlineColor = "red";
}
else if(!batchRegex.test(batch)){
  document.getElementById('batch').style.outlineColor = "red";
}
else if(batchRegex.test(batch)){
  document.getElementById('batch').style.outlineColor = "none";
}
}
<form method="post">
  <input type="text" maxlength="4" id="batch" name="batch" onkeyup="checkBatch(this.value)" required>
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
  </form>
```

Comment: Where is that regex?

Comment: Try onblur event

Comment: sorry I forgot to include it, here it is `var  batchRegex=/^[2][0][0-2][0-1]$/;` @MaheerAli

Comment: @herosuper it doesn't change the color at all

Comment: none is valid value for outline?

Comment: @herosuper I'm not sure, but before none I tried green and wasn't working

Comment: you can visit my answer in which I covered all validation for Form or other places. Visit my Link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/78050480/4335210

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple issues in your code:

1. `if (batch = ""){` should be `if (batch == ""){`
2. the regex `/^[2][0][0-2][0-1]$/` matches only the values:

   `2000`, `2001`, `2010`, `2011`, `2020`, `2021`

but you want to match all values between `2000` and `2021`.

Why not just try something simple like this:

```js
function checkBatch(batch){
  if (batch.value >= 2000 && batch.value <= 2021){
    batch.style.outlineColor = "green";
  } else {
    batch.style.outlineColor = "red";
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="post">
  <input type="text" maxlength="4" id="batch" name="batch" onkeyup="checkBatch(this)" required>
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
  </form>
```

and instead of changing inline styles via javascript, just add a class where you can then change the style with CSS something like..

```js
function checkBatch(batch){
  if (batch.value >= 2000 && batch.value <= 2021){
    batch.classList.remove('alert')
    batch.classList.add('success')
  } else {
    batch.classList.remove('success')
    batch.classList.add('alert')
  }
}
```

```css
input.alert {
  outline-color: red;
}
input.success {
  outline-color: green;
}
```

```html
<form method="post">
  <input type="text" maxlength="4" id="batch" name="batch" onkeyup="checkBatch(this)" required>
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use JS to change the style of the input, use the built in input validation available within HTML5 and CSS. Use CSS to automatically handle and update the style.

If instead you use a number input you can place min and max values

```
<input type="number" min=2000 max=2021 name="numyr" required >
```

You can then use css using the `:invalid` pseudo element.

```
input:invalid {
  outline: 2px solid pink;
}
```

If you're adamant about using a regex on an input value then you can use the `pattern` attribute

```
<input type="text" pattern="^[2][0][0-2][0-1]$" >
```

It's still possible to do further validation before submit using the form submit event.

```js
var  batchRegex=/^[2][0][0-2][0-1]$/;
function checkBatch(batch){
if (batch = ""){
  document.getElementById('batch').style.outlineColor = "red";
}
else if(!batchRegex.test(batch)){
  document.getElementById('batch').style.outlineColor = "red";
}
else if(batchRegex.test(batch)){
  document.getElementById('batch').style.outlineColor = "none";
}
}
```

```css
input{
  min-width: 100px;
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
}
input:invalid {
  outline: 2px solid pink;
}
```

```html
<form method="post">
  <input type="text" maxlength="4" id="batch" name="batch" onkeyup="checkBatch(this.value)" required>

  <input type="number" min=2000 max=2021 name="numyr" required >
 
  <input type="text" pattern="^[2][0][0-2][0-1]$" required >
  
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
  </form>
```